# "Error: invalid hook call" When using the hook within a function called on click of a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have a component which has a logic for following and unfollowing people. On button click, a function should be called which incudes the query logic. But when I press the button, it gives me "error: invalid hook call, hooks and only be called inside of the body of the function component"

These are my 2 functions for following and unfollowing logic:

```
function onFollowingClick() {
        const {isLoading: deleteFollowerLoading} = useQuery(["deleteFollower", myFollowerId], () => {
            deleteFollower(myFollowerId)
        })
        console.log("following call")
}

function onFollowClick() {
    const {isLoading:createFollowerLoading} = useQuery("createFollower",
        createFollower()
    )

    console.log("follower call")
}
```

This is the button where I have called the functions, and it is inside a map function, you can see it in onclick:

```
return (
    <div className={root}>
        <div className={body}>
                {                       
                    myFollowers && myFollowings && !followerLoading && (
                        followersData.map((e) => {
                        return(<>
                            <div className="data">
                            <Grid  templateColumns="repeat(2, 1fr)" width="100%" alignContent="center">
                            <GridItem w="100%" >
                            <Flex 
                            mt="10px">
                                <Avatar
                                size={isTabletOrMobile ? "xs" : "sm"}
                                src={e.requested_profile.s3PicURL}
                                />
                                
                                <Text
                                w="100%"
                                wrap="off"
                                ml="5px"
                                isTruncated
                                fontSize={isTabletOrMobile ? "sm" : "md"}
                                >
                                    {e.requested_profile.Userlink}
                                </Text>
                            </Flex>
                            </GridItem>
                            <GridItem>
                                <Flex justifyContent="flex-end">
                                <Button
                                w="100px"
                                h="30px"
                                mt="8px"
                                onClick = { () => {
                                    if(myFollowings.includes(e.requested_profile.Userlink)){
                                        onFollowingClick()
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        onFollowClick()
                                    }
                                } }
                                variant={myFollowings.includes(e.requested_profile.Userlink) ? "outline" : "solid"}
                                width={isTabletOrMobile ? "50px" : "60px"}>
                                    {
                                        myFollowings.includes(e.requested_profile.Userlink) ? "Following" : "Follow"
                                    }
                                </Button>
                                </Flex>
                            </GridItem>
                            </Grid>
                            </div>
                            </>
                        ) 
                    })
                    )
                }
        </div>
    </div>

    
)
```

please tell me how do I solve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. You cannot use hooks anywhere unless it's at a top component level (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks).
2. You using `react-query` and trying to mutate state using `useQuery`. This hook is used to fetch the data. If you want to do mutations, you should use `useMutation` hook. But please note these hooks should be at a top level too, you cannot call it from a click handler as we call regular functions.

So, your steps are:

- define `useMutation` hooks with the callbacks and the backend interaction logic
- when you click buttons you call `mutationFollow.mutate({ id: item.id })`
- to invalidate your state after mutations you should use `onSuccess` callback:

```
onSuccess: () => {
   queryClient.invalidateQueries('followers')
},
```

One of options to do what you want could be:

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient()

const Component = () => {
  const { isLoading, data: followers } = useQuery('followers')
  const mutationFollow = useMutation(
    follower => {
      return axios.post('/follow', follower)
    },
    {
      onSuccess: () => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries('followers')
      },
    },
  )

  const mutationUnfollow = useMutation(
    follower => {
      return axios.post('/unfollow', follower)
    },
    {
      onSuccess: () => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries('followers')
      },
    },
  )

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  return followers.map(item => (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          mutationFollow.mutate({ id: item.id })
        }}
      >
        Follow
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          mutationUnfollow.mutate({ id: item.id })
        }}
      >
        Unfollow
      </button>
    </div>
  ))
}
```